# Flutter drawer menu open behind flutter_webview_plugin

Tags: flutter, flutterwebviewplugin

I am new in flutter i am using flutter_webview_plugin for open my web in flutter application with drawer navigation menu.
But the issue is  my drawer menu is behind the flutter_webview
Maybe the flutter_webview load after drawer menu

Check this image this is for issue

[image: Check this image this is for issue]

Answer (score 1):

If you are opening the link from the `Drawer` (by clicking on a drawer item), then am guessing you are not closing the `Drawer`, that is why it is showing on the background,
If so, assign a `key` to the `Scaffold`  then call `key.openEndDrawer()` to close the drawer programmatically, before you open the `WebView`

Comment: @m-m-hasibuzzaman thank you for your reply but you can not understand my question
my question is load my application with home page and on my home page i open webview using flutter_webview_plugin then after i click on menu icon for open drawer menu that menu open behind of that webview

Comment: which drawer are you opening by clicking the menu icon? website or app?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit late answer, I couldn't find any solution by searching but I found a solution that works for me. when I m using [flutter_webview_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin) I've noticed that when I want to navigate to another page, the page is showing in the background for Android. This is not happening for iOS. Here is how I dealt with this problem:

```dart
flutterWebViewPlugin.hide();
```

When I want to navigate to another page I called this function inside [flutter_webview_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin). After that when I finished my work on another page I called:

```dart
flutterWebViewPlugin.show();
```